# Replacing Load-Bearing 2x4 wall with beam and posts - Basement

Tags: basement, framing

I would like replace a 64" section of a load bearing wall with a beam and 2 support posts. The current wall is 2x4 pressure treated sill plate on top of poured concrete, 5 2x4 vertical supports and double 2x4 header.
[image]

I am looking for advice on materials to use. I am thinking about using 4x4 p/t supports, and doubled 2x8 for the beam. On one the left end of the new beam I would probably just nail the support beam the existing 2x4 on the other end I'm not really sure, but it will be perpendicular to a another wall that will be built (see proposed design below). Will this work?

If there are any major structural concerns, I could make the span shorter, but I would like to keep it as wide as possible. How should the beam be attached to the supports? Finally, any considerations for distributing the weight at the base? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: "64' section" - did you really mean 64 *feet*, or 64 *inches*?

Comment: oh man..inches. pretty big detail to miss, thanks for the notice

Comment: I'd call in an engineer on any substantial change to loadbearing structures. They can suggest best/least-cost solutions and materials (in my case, that involved sistering a joist with a steel C-beam). And given the consequences of getting this wrong...

Comment: Not saying this isn't load bearing but how are you sure it is?  It isn't normal for a small section of basement to have a framed load bearing section.  Also if it was load bearing I would think it would extend to the wall.

Comment: DMoore, it is my understanding that *most* load bearing walls will have the doubled header. House is 2 story and directly above this is a wall that extends to the 2nd level which would definitely be supporting 2nd floor joists. Directly above is the base of the stairs to the 2nd floor. If not load bearing, it certainly provides stability. doesnt support the roof trusses though.

Comment: @jriggs I wouldn't put too much trust in the double header to tell you anything. Most framed walls have a double header in standard construction regardless of whether the wall is load bearing.  However based on the picture, it does look like joists rest on top of the remaining part of the wall.

Comment: @jriggs Is this a picture taken AFTER the portion of the wall was removed or did the wall always end as shown in the picture?